# Idiomatic way to produce compiler error in if constexpr branch

Tags: c++, c++17, assert, static-assert, if-constexpr

I found myself with this type of code,

```
template<class T>
void f(T const& t){
        if constexpr(std::is_same<T, double>{}) call_a(t); // call_a only compiles for double
   else if constexpr(std::is_same<T, float >{}) call_b(t); // call_b only compiles for float
   else                                         assert(0 && "not implemented");
}
```

**What would be an idiomatic way to produce a compiler error instead of a runtime error?** (a hard error would be ok.)

I though this would work,

```
   else                                         static_assert(0, "not implemented");
```

but it makes the code unconditionally not compile.

Of course, I could add outside the condition `static_assert(std::is_same<T, double>{} or std::is_Same<T, float>` but basically I am repeating the conditions from the if-statement.

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20200311-00/?p=103553

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20200319-00/?p=103572